# Mathematica Installation Problem

Tags: software-installation, 13.10, mathematica

Ubuntu 13.10 - 64 bit

Mathematica 9.

```
CRITICAL FAILURE: PrintIntroduction() Error 

  $ProductTitle not defined.
```

[image: Mathematica Installation Problem]

Help me to install.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't use directory/folder name with space.

Example:

```
  Wrong  : "Mathematica 9"
  Correct: "mathematica"
```